# Replace value in XML with Ant

Tags: xml, ant, xml-parsing

I have a xml file, with format:

```
<ofbiz-component name="catalina">
  <container name="catalina-container" loaders="main">
    <property name="ajp-connector" value="connector">
      <property name="port" value="8010"/>
    </property>
    <property name="http-connector" value="connector">
      <property name="port" value="8081"/>
    </property>
    <property name="https-connector" value="connector">
      <property name="port" value="8411"/>
    </property>
  </container>  
</ofbiz-component>
```

I would like to replace port value in each `<property name="port"` tag, i have tried with beanshell, groovy,... but i have to work with standard ant(no beanshell, no javascript, no groovy).

Any idea is appreciated :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You could make a template of your XML file:**

```
<ofbiz-component name="catalina">
  <container name="catalina-container" loaders="main">
    <property name="ajp-connector" value="connector">
      <property name="port" value="@ajp-port@"/>
    </property>
    <property name="http-connector" value="connector">
      <property name="port" value="@http-port@"/>
    </property>
    <property name="https-connector" value="connector">
      <property name="port" value="@https-port@"/>
    </property>
  </container>  
</ofbiz-component>
```

**And then use the [`replace` ant task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replace.html):**

```
<replace file="fname.xml" token="@ajp-port@" value="8010"/>
<replace file="fname.xml" token="@http-port@" value="8081"/>
<replace file="fname.xml" token="@https-port@" value="8411"/>
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, i will wait for another answer in one day.